# How do I make a payment from a node address to a wallet using cardano-cli on mainnet?

Tags: documentation, cardano-cli, payment

I followed the documentation for building a Relay and Block node.
Part of that involved sending some ADA to the block producing node's address, to be used as a stake pool deposit.

However, the documentation showed the deposit as 2,000,000 lovelace. In fact it's 500,000,000 according to `mainnet-shelley-genesis.json`, and that's too rich for me to play with tutorials. So I'd like to return the ADA from the Block node to my wallet.

I found this document showing [how to make a payment](https://www.coincashew.com/coins/overview-ada/guide-how-to-build-a-haskell-stakepool-node#18-9-send-a-simple-transaction-example).
I calculated the amount to be the total holding balance of the Block address, less the fee.

The transaction failed. Here's the error:

```
Command failed: transaction submit  Error: Error while submitting tx: ShelleyTxValidationError ShelleyBasedEraMary (ApplyTxError [LedgerFailure (UtxowFailure (UtxoFailure (OutputTooSmallUTxO [(Addr Mainnet (KeyHashObj (KeyHash "f1a1639d8012278565242d449223c7d40e6e87c81021b99f3bac4749")) (StakeRefBase (KeyHashObj (KeyHash "a9f00a2910b88d5aacd9ef1c8ef4d06ebf7faf1618876a60ed088cc1"))),Value 1 (fromList []))])))])
```

I don't understand the error, and I'm wondering if the documentation is outdated (given the stake deposit was wrong).

Is there a more current document showing how to submit a payment, using cardano-cli and keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you like using Python, try the [Cardano-Tools](https://gitlab.com/viper-staking/cardano-tools) library that I put together. Its basically a smart wrapper around the CLI that takes care of extra steps for you such as selecting the UTxO(s). You need the `cardano-cli` installed and a synced `cardano-node` running. Below is some example code.

```
from cardano_tools import ShelleyTools

# Test Inputs (example paths)
path_to_cli = "/home/user/.cabal/bin/cardano-cli"
path_to_socket = "/home/user/relay-node/db/node.socket"
working_dir = "/home/user/.cardano-tools/"

# Create a ShelleyTools object
shelley = ShelleyTools(
    path_to_cli, 
    path_to_socket, 
    working_dir, 
    network="--mainnet"  # Can also use testnet magic here
 )

 amt = 10 # Ada to send
 to_addr = "addr1..." # Address to send the ADA to
 from_addr = "addr1..." # Address to send the ADA from
 key_file = "/path/to/addr.skey" # path to the signing key file

 shelley.send_payment(amt, to_addr, from_addr, key_file)
```

Note that you need the signing key file that belongs to the specific address that you are sending the ADA from.

Comment: Thank you, I have not used Python for a while, but I will certainly give it a go.

Comment: Hello @nalyd88, that worked just fine after a bit playing about.  Thank you.

Comment: Happy to help! Please feel free to leave feedback on our library or make pull requests.

Answer (score 3):

If possible, always use the official documentation to protect yourself from scams. For sending a simple transaction using the `cardano-cli`, have [a look at docs.cardano.org](https://docs.cardano.org/projects/cardano-node/en/latest/stake-pool-operations/simple_transaction.html).

As for the error, when inspecting it, you will find it says `OutputTooSmallUTxO`. This is because of the `minUTxOValue` protocol parameters which is used to prevent dusting up the UTXO set. It is now set to `10000000` lovelaces, that means you cannot send an output smaller than this amount, which is probably something you are trying to do.

Comment: It's also worth practicing with cardano-cli on the testnet rather than using real ADA. Configuration files and instructions are found at docs.cardano.org